# Save method for each Enum

Tags: java, methods, enums

I've created an Enum. Now I want to save a method for each Enum. These methods are in different classes. How can I accomplish this?
I mean something like this:

```
public enum FooEnum {

    A(Person::setAge),
    B(Test::setTest);

    private final Function</* What to enter here */, Object> function;

    private FooEnum(final Function</* ... */, Object> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public Function</* ... */, Object> getFunction() {
        return function;
    } 
}
```

Obviously this won't compile.
"Person" and "Test" are just some example classes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Function` you could use `Runnable`. And since an enum are static constants you'll need to define your methods static as well:

```
  public static class Person {
    public static void setAge() {

    }
  }

  public enum FooEnum {

    A(Person::setAge);

    private final Runnable function;

    private FooEnum(Runnable function) {
      this.function = function;
    }

    public Runnable getFunction() {
      return function;
    } 
  }
```